# PhoneGap Angular iOS App displaying white screen only

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

We've built a HTML/JS iOS app using Angular which works perfectly on desktop browsers but when I wrap it up as PhoneGap project and try to run it on my device, it simply loads the splash screen which fades out to a **blank white** screen. I've been looking around for similar issues with the routing maybe? I just can't figure it out. Can anybody help?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid-12.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var is_ios = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (is_ios) {

        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iosbugfix.css" />').appendTo("head");

    };

    </script>

    <base href="/">

</head>

<body ng-app="appItmt" ng-controller="dataController">

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    var itmtApp = angular.module("appItmt", ["ngRoute", "cgBusy"]);

    itmtApp.config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/how-to/', {
                    templateUrl: 'how-to.html',
                    controller: 'dataController'
                })
                 .when('/privacy/', {
                     templateUrl: 'privacy.html',
                     controller: 'dataController'
                 })
                 .when('/about/', {
                     templateUrl: 'about.html',
                     controller: 'dataController'
                 })
                 .otherwise({
                     templateUrl: 'main.html',
                     controller: 'dataController'

                 });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    ]);
}());
```

Comment: Have you configured your config.xml with splashscreen and its delay ? If not then it should be looking for another "Default-Portrait" image file

Comment: @VikrantMore Yes - I've added: 

<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />


<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" /> 

But no joy...

Comment: It has a splashscreen, but that fades out to white.

Comment: looks like it is a javascript error. Does the console show any errors ?

Comment: @vbotio no, the console doesn't show any errors when I run it through Safari.

Comment: are you using just cordova or ionic as well ? I'm not sure how good cordova works with angular, and ionic was built specifically for angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the deviceready event before running your JavaScript.  See the Cordova documentation for this [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready).

This signals that PhoneGap/Cordova is ready to go and it is safe to run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code this may help:

1. Change your config.xml in yourapp/platforms/ios/cordova/ and add following preference:

   `<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />`
2. The add following code to your app.js:

   `angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
         .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
             $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
               setTimeout(function() {
                 navigator.splashscreen.hide();
             }, 100);
         });
    })`

Try rebuilding your application : `$ ionic build ios`

And try it `$ ionic emulate ios`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What makes debugging worse is that app runs ok with `ionic run android` but not with `ionic build android`

What I found out is that my app works fine without 
`<base href="/">`
which at the same time means I have to remove
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Then I found the answer [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1930)

When building the app base should be changed to `<base href=".">`

Comment: Thanks for the input. We just couldn't get around the path issue, so we added all the code for each page into the index file and referenced it there. Luckily there wasn't much and it solved our problem.